# Remote machine thru powershell such as login user

Tags: powershell

I need to automate a machine at a specific time like this :

1. Power on thru WOL
2. Tell the machine to login as a specific user.
3. Open up a browser and go to an url
4. Stay open for 30min
5. Shutdown machine

I think i have all steps besides 2. Is it possible to tell a remote machine to login so the user in front of it can see it logs in ?

/donnib

Comment: Powershell supports remoting through interactive and fan-out methods:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/25/an-introduction-to-powershell-remoting-part-three-interactive-and-fan-out-remoting/

However, it does not support GUI login as if the person at the keyboard hit CTRL+ALT+DEL, entered a UN/PW and logged into Windows.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question which means it's not possible.

Comment: No problem. If I post that as the answer would you mark it?